# How were the Mechas able to restore Monica's memory?

Tags: ai-artificial-intelligence

At the end of *A.I. - Artificial Intelligence*, the Mecha leader tells David that they can clone Monica, and also restore her memory from a time-space trail.

**How does that work?** How could they get her memory from this trail and insert it inside a human body?

Comment: The technical term is "hand waving."

Answer (score 3):

The quote from the film is

> *"We also wondered, **would it be possible to retrieve a memory trace in
>   resonance with a recreated body.** And do you know what we found? We
>   found... the very fabric of space-time itself appeared to store
>   information about every event which had ever occured in the past."*

And that appears to be the entire sum of knowledge we have on the procedure. Evidently they extract the memory from space time and somehow shove it into the body. Unfortunately the procedure causes the memory trace to break down and the subject goes back to being a brainless clone after a day.

Comment: and why the fake Monica didn't ask about her husband Henry
and her real son Martin?

Comment: @Tito - An excellent question and one that isn't answered in the film

Comment: Why Teddy was angry when they arrived at the end of the world?